# Customized Sort order in Swift

Tags: swift, sorting

I have a set of strings I need to sort in an order which is not Latin alphabetic.
Specifically, I have a string "AiyawbpfmnrhHxXzsSqkgtTdD" which specifies the sorting order, i.e., "y" comes before "a", but after "A". In case you are interested, this is the sort order for ancient Egyptian hieroglyphs as specified in the Manuel de Codage.

In Swift, is there a convenient way to specify a predicate or other approach for this type of collation order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn your alphabet into a `Dictionary` that maps each `Character` to its integer position in the alphabet:

```
import Foundation

let hieroglyphAlphabet = "AiyawbpfmnrhHxXzsSqkgtTdD"

let hieroglyphCodes = Dictionary(
    uniqueKeysWithValues: hieroglyphAlphabet
        .enumerated()
        .map { (key: $0.element, value: $0.offset) }
)
```

Next, extend `StringProtocol` with a property that returns an array of such alphabetic positions:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var hieroglyphEncoding: [Int] { map { hieroglyphCodes[$0] ?? -1 } }
}
```

I'm turning non-alphabetic characters into -1, so they will be treated as less-than alphabetic characters. You could turn them into `.max` to treat them as greater-than, or use a more complex type than `Int` if you need more special treatment.

Now you can sort an array of strings by `hieroglyphEncoding`, using the `lexicographicallyPrecedes` method of `Sequence`:

```
let unsorted = "this is the sort order".components(separatedBy: " ")
let sorted = unsorted.sorted {
    $0.hieroglyphEncoding.lexicographicallyPrecedes($1.hieroglyphEncoding)
}
print(sorted)
```

Output:

```
["order", "is", "sort", "the", "this"]
```

It is not efficient to recompute the `hieroglyphEncoding` of each string on demand during the sort, so if you have many strings to sort, you should wrap each string and its encoding into a wrapper for sorting or use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: Very cool idea! Many thanks!!. Considering the database from I draw these strings has 50k+ entries, and the typical sort runs 50 - 1500 strings at a time, I agree that precomputing the hieroglyphEncoding makes absolute sense!